# meteor bindEnvironment does not allow Meteor.userId()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following code, where I need to get Access to the current user. Therefore I want to check `Meteor.userId()`. However this fails and returns the log message: `Failed to bind environment`

```
 ShareJS.model.on('create', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (docName, data) {
            console.log(Meteor.userId())
            //some more code

        }, function () {
            console.log('Failed to bind environment')
        }));
```

What is wrong on this usage of bindEnvironment in Meteor?

If I do not use `Meteor.userId()` inside the callback, everything works fine, and my callback is bound to the environment.

Comment: Where is the `ShareJS.model.on` call? In a method/publication or something like that? Or at the top level?

Comment: It is a server only method on top level.

Comment: pretty sure Meteor.userId() is only available on the server when a user calls a method (within that fiber).